# How to draw edges between nodes in different sublayouts so that they are behind the rest of the graph in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a minimalish example of my drawing:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} []

  \graph [nodes=draw,
  grow down]
  {
    //[layered layout,name=cat1,nodes={fill=red!50}]{
      Cat1[rectangle] -> {110
        , 492};
      492 -> 371;
    };

    //[layered layout,name=cat2,nodes={fill=green!50}]{
      Cat2[x=+4cm,rectangle] -> 140;
      140 -> 150;
      150 -> {305, 325};
    };

    //[layered layout,name=cat3,nodes={fill=yellow!50}]{
      Cat3[x=-5cm,rectangle] -> {101
        , 156 -> {365, 326}};
    };
        
(cat3 365) -> (cat2 150);
  
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following:
[image: minimal example rendering]

I would like to render the line between (Cat3 365) and (Cat2 150) behind other nodes (like Cat1 371). I tried using the `backgrounds` library, but I couldn't get it to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: [`edges behind nodes`](https://tikz.dev/gd-usage-tikz#pgf.edges:behind:nodes) should be default … maybe it doesn't work because the top layout is not a graphdrawing one but an “online” one (i.e. one from the `graphs` library). You could always end that one graph operation and append `[behind path] graph{(cat3 365) -> (cat2 150)}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I can't parse exactly what you want me to try from your comment. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`edges behind nodes`](https://tikz.dev/gd-usage-tikz#pgf.edges:behind:nodes) is the default drawing order, it seems to only work when all edges are part of a graphdrawing layout.

However, your edge isn't part of a `layered layout` but of the Online Placement Strategy [`Cartesian placement`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/grow:down) due to `grow down`.

Since you don't use that even, I've replaced it with [`no placement`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/no:placement).

While there's probably a way to specify a layout for the three sublayouts so that that edge is considered, in your use-case it's much easier to end one `graph` operation and start another one after [`behind path`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/behind:path) (which despite the manual not mentioning it also applies to edges and not only nodes), meaning all following edges will be placed behind everything on that path and the foreground (i.e. the whole diagram).

This will also place this new edge behind all other edges but that won't be noticeable in this simple diagram.

### Code

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \graph [nodes=draw, no placement] {
    //[layered layout, name=cat1, nodes={fill=red!50}]{
      Cat1[rectangle] -> {110, 492 -> 371};
    };
    //[layered layout, name=cat2, nodes={fill=green!50}]{
      Cat2[x=+4cm,rectangle] -> 140 -> 150 -> {305, 325};
    };
    //[layered layout, name=cat3, nodes={fill=yellow!50}]{
      Cat3[x=-5cm,rectangle] -> {101, 156 -> {365, 326}};
    };
  } [behind path] graph{(cat3 365) -> (cat2 150)};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]